# Select from dropdown using selenium and python not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to develop a script in python that logs me on a website and then select a project from a dropdown menu. I can log in on the website but the project selection is not working for me...
I tried multiple variants(find_by_id/xpath/visible_text etc.) with and without '.click()' or 'select'.

website:

```
<select style="font-size: 80%;position:relative; top:-1px;" name="testproject" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="62802146" title="Project" selected="selected">Project</option>
```

my code:

```
def login(url,login, username, password, password, submit):
  driver.get(url)
  driver.find_element_by_id(login).send_keys(username)
  driver.find_element_by_id(password).send_keys(password)
  button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/input").click()
  time.sleep(1)
  selected_project = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div"))
  selected_project.select_by_value('62802146')
```

Edit:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMIoL.png)

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: May its because of the xpath in the `selected_project`. Try this xpath : `//select[@name='testproject']` (Considering that there is only one `select` tag with name `testproject`).

Comment: @Prophet it's a private testlink server( https://testlink.org/)

Comment: @pmadhu Unfortunately this solution is not working either...
When using selenium to access a dropdown should I see the dropdown being automatically clicked and all the option shown after, or is everything happening in 'background'?
Because after the waiting time when it comes for the dropdown to be selected, nothing happens

Comment: @TiberiuRoman -  We should be able to see the clicking operation on dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an angular based website, that will require Explicit wait.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[onchange*='this.form.submit'][name='testproject']"))))
select.select_by_visible_text('Project')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Also I see you are using `62802146` value which is default selected option in UI, so that's the reason you do not see any changes in drop down with browser automation, so try to select 2 oe 3 option to see significant changes.

Comment: still not working, I added the error in the main post

Comment: I know this is the URL https://testlink.org/, how do I reach to that drop down ?